# Estimate SQL query time

Tags: mysql, timing

If

```
SELECT attr FROM t WHERE attr2>=0 LIMIT 10000;
```

took about 0.26 sec.  How much time (very roughly) would

```
SELECT attr FROM t WHERE attr2>700;
```

take to run?

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT attr FROM t WHERE attr2>700;
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      |      t        | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 769111 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

#### EDIT: more info, (in case it matters)

I recently updated 1 or 2 attributes in about 5000 rows in the table.

When I ran `SELECT attr FROM t WHERE attr2>700;` it did not finish in 20 min before I aborted.

Comment: The only thing I can say for definite is both will be faster if you put an index on attr2. Might as well have asked how this piece of string was.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try with maths ;)

10.000  rows => 0.26s

769.111 rows => (769.111 * 0.26 / 10.000) => **about 20s**

But this is a pure theoretical estimation.

Wikipedia [Cross-multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication)

Comment: If it is that obvious, there would not have been the question posted here.  I ran `SELECT attr FROM t WHERE attr2>700;` and waited for at least 5 min and it's still running.

Comment: It you're not looking for that obvious answer, why provide us a time for another query ? Number of rows if the only one parameter we can take in account from your informations.

Comment: What other information do you need to see to give a possible explanation to the seemingly long time to run the full command?

Comment: @user001, it is not possible to do such a calculation. If you had a scenario, where there was a massive update on the table and you have a huge amount of “outdated” records, database will have to scan them all. It is too abstract question to answer, too much other factors (not mentioned) that can and _will_ affect the performance.

Comment: So if I recently updated values in many rows, a query like `SELECT attr FROM t WHERE attr2>700;` can take significantly longer time than it did before the update?

Comment: You should never work on as much datas. If you are, there's probably a conception problem in amount. I think trying to find some factors you can use to avoid this mass-work is the best thing to do, but I don't know all the ins and outs.